# Add A Global jQuery Script To Wordpress Website

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to make it so that whenever anybody clicks on a button with a specific ID this jQuery script fires the Facebook Pixel's 'Add to Cart' event. Here's the code I have so far:

```
// add to cart
$('#offerbutton').click(function(e){
    fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
});
```

How can I make this script globally accessible so I don't have to go through my Wordpress website page my page to paste the code in manually?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have access to the template/theme files?

Comment: @disinfor I do, yes

Comment: You only want to track add to cart for one item, or for many? How will you determine which items you want to track?

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably suggest just using a plugin to do it, as it allows you to easily add/remove it, completely decoupled from any theme you're using. You can *always* just add the js in the header/footer, but this way is very low-overhead and is dead easy.

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/wordpress/custom-js/